# How to Preserve the Collapsed code lines from expanding on applying source formatting in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, formatting, adobe, dreamweaver

In **Dreamweaver**, How to make the **collapsed code lines to be locked** until I manually expand them by clicking on the **"plus"** icon.

It shouldn't expand even when I apply **Source Formatting** for the document.

Answer (score 0):

Check the official document. link - https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/collapsing-code.html

Comment: No, Dreamweaver doesn't support locking.